# ¿Cómo obtener los valores de una columna sólo si un valor específico existe en otra columna?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo una dataframe y me gustaria obtener solo las líneas para las que hay un valor específico.

Por ejemplo con la dataframe siguiente solo quiero los code con liking:

```
        code    question_name
2160    005756  Age group
2161    005756  Age group
2162    005756  Age group
2163    005756  Liking
2164    005758  Liking
2165    005759  Age group
2166    005759  Age group
2167    005759  Age group
2168    005760  Liking
2169    005756  Age group
```

Me gustaria obtener 005756, 005758 y 005760, pero no 005759

Comment: `df[df.question_name=="Liking"].code.unique()`

Answer (score 0):

Mediante indexación booleana:

Si quieres obtener valores que sean DIFERENTES al filtro, tienes que usar la expresión `!=`, que excluirá de tu DataFrame los datos que contengan el valor a comparar.

En tu caso, `df2 = df[df['code'] != '005759']`
que te dará como resultado:

```
     code      quest
0  005756  Age group
1  005756  Age group
2  005756  Age group
3  005756     Liking
4  005758     Liking
8  005760     Liking
9  005756  Age group
```

**EDITADO: Como has cambiado la pregunta, edito para incluir tu nuevo requisito.**

Del mismo modo, si quieres obtener solo los valores que conicidan con determinado valor en otro columna, la expresión debe ser `==`, por lo que quedaría así: `df2 = df[df['quest'] == 'Liking']` y el resultado sería este:

```
     code   quest
3  005756  Liking
4  005758  Liking
8  005760  Liking
```

Comment: Muchas gracias y como obtener todos los code por lo cuales no hay ningun Liking cualquier sea la linea?

Comment: La respuesta está planteada con los criterios de tu pregunta. Si te sirvió, acepta esta respuesta, y abre una nueva pregunta con las necesidades que tengas o los problemas que encuentras, y te la responderé sin ningún problema.

Answer (score 0):

Eliges todas las filas del dataframe que cumplan tu condición,(`df[df.question_name=="Liking"]`) y de ellas te quedas con la columna `.code`. Aplicas `set()` al resultado para eliminar duplicados, y ya tienes lo que buscabas: todos los `code` en los que se da al menos una vez la question_name "Liking".

Es decir:

```py
>>> tienen_liking = set(df[df.question_name=="Liking"].code)
>>> tienen_liking
{5756, 5758, 5760}
```

Para el caso contrario (por el que preguntas en un comentario), es decir, todos los `code` que **nunca** presentan un caso "Liking", lo que necesitas en el fondo es el conjunto complementario del que acabamos de encontrar.

Se obtendrá por tanto restando al conjunto de todos los `code` los que habíamos encontrado en el caso anterior:

```py
>>> no_tienen_liking = set(df.code) - tienen_liking
>>> no_tienen_liking
{5759}
```

Si quieres ver los registros completos correspondientes a estos casos, puedes usar algo de este estilo:

```
>>> df[df.code.isin(no_tienen_liking)]
      code question_name
2165  5759     Age group
2166  5759     Age group
2167  5759     Age group
```

Comment: No se mucho de Pandas, pero no serviría también `set(df[df.question_name!="Liking"].code)` en lugar de restar dos conjuntos? Si la respuesta es no, por que?

Comment: Es para evitar hacer dos consultas diferentes al dataframe?

Comment: No, porque con tu expresión lo que consigues es el conjunto de los "codes" que en algún caso tuvieron question distinta de "Liking", en lugar de los codes cuya question _siempre_ fue distinta de "Liking". No es lo mismo decir "todas las especies animales en las que existen individuos no-verdes" que "todas las especies de animales en las que todos sus individuos son no-verdes". En las primeras podrían aparecer ranas (pues hay ranas rojas). En las segundas no (pues hay ranas verdes). Está relacionado con la diferencia entre los cuantificadores universales "existe" (∃) o "para todo" (∀)

Comment: De hecho tu consulta produciría `{5756, 5759}` en este caso, porque el 5756 tiene casos distintos de "Liking" (como cuando es "Age group")

Comment: Ahhh, ya entiendo! Pensé que todos los code tenían el mismo valor en question_name. Por ejemplo que todos los code 5756 tenian un question_name linking.